# Bluetooth error "Unable to load key file"

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

I am on 22.04 and I have an error with my bluetooth. I can turn Bluetooth on, I can see other Bluetooth device to connect with, but I cannot connect. The toggle **Connection** doesn't work.

Running `sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service` returns the  following:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-02-01 12:22:59 EET; 12min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 7426 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38166)
     Memory: 808.0K
        CPU: 95ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─7426 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
bluetoothd[7426]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
bluetoothd[7426]: Starting SDP server
bluetoothd[7426]: Bluetooth management interface 1.21 initialized
bluetoothd[7426]: src/device.c:load_gatt_db() Unable to load key file from /var/lib/bluetooth/84:5C:F3:92:6F:4D/cache/6E:92:30:B5:4A:0D: (No such file or directory)
bluetoothd[7426]: src/device.c:load_gatt_db() No cache for 6E:92:30:B5:4A:0D
bluetoothd[7426]: Too small Add Device complete event
```

**Edit:**

The output of `sudo dmesg | grep -i blue` is:

```
[    3.356236] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.356430] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.356431] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.356433] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.356434] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.356447] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.427475] Bluetooth: hci0: Legacy ROM 2.x revision 5.0 build 25 week 20 2015
[    3.428603] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-22.50.19.14.f.bseq
[    3.662489] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel BT fw patch 0x43 completed & activated
[    3.996584] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.996587] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.996589] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  410.123831] Bluetooth: hci0: link tx timeout
```

Comment: Please add output of `sudo dmesg | grep -i blue` command.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added it to the original question.

Comment: Try to reset the headphones. Find a manual for them. Also remove other devices.

Comment: I did the reset and now the toggle in the settings (as in the screenshot) seems to work, but by the moment I turn it to ON, it gets back to OFF again.

Comment: There is another device showing "Not Set Up". Did you try to remove it? The problem is with some other `6E:92:30:B5:4A:0D` device.

Comment: How can I remove all devices?

Comment: You can click them and remove.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem today when I tried to pair my bluetooth mouse on both Windows and Ubuntu of the same PC. I renamed `/var/lib/bluetooth/PC:MAC:ADDRESS/MOUSE:MAC:ADDRESS` to match the mouse address on Windows, and when I restart `bluetooth.service`, it fails with "Unable to load key file" error. Turns out there need to be a cached attribute file in `/var/lib/bluetooth/PC:MAC:ADDRESS/cache` directory, which should match the name and content of `MOUSE:MAC:ADDRESS` directory too. So I have to remove `MOUSE:MAC:ADDRESS` directory (which in your case is `6E:92:30:B5:4A:0D`), restart bluetooth service, and everything works fine again (though I still have to repair my mouse).

Note that removing this directory requires `sudo -i` first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the exact same issue, but running 22.04 I had an issue where any bluetooth controller that I tried to pair (Of multiple types/manufacturers) would fail to pair completely, with the controller showing connected but the KDE dialog would fail to connect and ask to restart the wizard.  After this any attempt to connect with the controller would result in endless connect/disconnect messages.  Here's an example of the pairing and subsequent connection/disconnect messages from bluetoothctl:

```
[NEW] Device 98:B6:E8:96:64:C9 Gamesir-T4pro_64C9
[CHG] Device 98:B6:E8:96:64:C9 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Controller 00:02:72:AC:61:90 Discovering: no
[CHG] Device 98:B6:E8:96:64:C9 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 98:B6:E8:96:64:C9 Bonded: yes
[CHG] Device 98:B6:E8:96:64:C9 Modalias: usb:v1949p0402d011B
[CHG] Device 98:B6:E8:96:64:C9 UUIDs: 00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 98:B6:E8:96:64:C9 UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 98:B6:E8:96:64:C9 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 98:B6:E8:96:64:C9 Paired: yes
[CHG] Device 98:B6:E8:96:64:C9 WakeAllowed: yes
[CHG] Device 98:B6:E8:96:64:C9 Trusted: yes
[CHG] Device 98:B6:E8:96:64:C9 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 98:B6:E8:96:64:C9 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 98:B6:E8:96:64:C9 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 98:B6:E8:96:64:C9 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 98:B6:E8:96:64:C9 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 98:B6:E8:96:64:C9 Connected: no
```

In the end, I tried removing the entire BT adapter directory (Desperation, I know):

```
rm -rf /usr/var/lib/bluetooth/00:02:72:AC:61:90
```

The bluetooth service failed to start since it was missing the bluetoothd executable from /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd, not sure how.  I tried linking the source and restarting the service, and everything works!

```
ln -s /usr/sbin/bluetoothd /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd
systemctl restart bluetooth.service
```

VERY strange, this just started happening out of the blue (ha ha), and I even switched from an onboard BT adapter to a USB adapter with no effect, so the removal/link/restart was the only thing that worked.  I should mention that I tried all the normal things: updating, rebooting, restarting the service, unpairing/repairing, etc. with no luck.